# Ensure that Modal is Always Centered

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog div which, depending on what the user clicks, could contain content of varying size.

How can I ensure that it is always centered horizontally within the window, regardless the content size inside the modal, and regardless the window size?

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robarwebservices/tvj4x10s/1/) of what I have.

**html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="openModal('asfghgggggggg');">Open Modal - smaller content</a>
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="openModal('a;lsdkjfa;ksdjhgfsakldjfhaksjdhfkasldjhf a sdlkfjhsa fg sdfghdsfgsdfgsdfgsdf g dsfgdsfgsdfgsdfgsdffgsdfgsdfgs dfg sdf g sdfg sdf g sdfg sdf g sd fgdsf g sdf g');">Open Modal - larger content</a>

<div id="emod">
<p><a href="#" onclick="closeModal();">close</a></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#emod 
{          
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -100px;
    padding: 20px 100px 100px 100px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

**JS**

```
function openModal(txt){
     var modalContainer = document.getElementById('emod');        
        modalContainer.style.display = 'block';   
        modalContainer.innerHTML += txt;
}


function closeModal(){
     var modalContainer = document.getElementById('emod');        
        modalContainer.style.display = 'none';   
        modalContainer.innerHTML ='<p><a href="#" onclick="closeModal();">close</a></p>';
}
```

I am using pure js for this feature, but we do load jQuery and could use that if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the modal like this:

```
#emod {    
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Safari */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

To fix the issue with scrolling to top, you must prevent default, as you are using a click on an anchor tag to open your modal.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return openModal('asfghgggggggg');">Open Modal - smaller content</a>
```

Then add `return false;` at the end of your functions

Comment: This doesn't handle cases where you might be scrolled down the page a bit when activating the modal... the modal still shows up at the top instead of in the middle of the viewport

Answer (score 0):

Here's my modal code: https://jsfiddle.net/fd4o3o6s/

Usage is a simple matter of

```
new popup();
```

It supports anything I can think about ^^